# Flatlist change renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hey so lets say I got a`FlatList` and want to change its `renderItem` how would I do it?

```
<FlatList
  data={this.data}
  renderItem={{item}} => <Video id={item.id}>}
  onViewableItemsChanged={(changed)=> console.log(changed)}
/>
```

On the piece of code above how could I change the `<Video />` to include a `paused` property once `onViewableItemsChanged` is triggered ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add `setState` in the `onViewableItemsChanged` to store the changes then use that in the `renderItem` to pause the video.

Comment: Can you please give me an example with the code above?

`<FlatList
  data={this.data}
  renderItem={{item}} => <Video id={item.id} paused={this.state.paused}>}
  onViewableItemsChanged={(changed)=>  changed && this.setState({paused:true})}
/>`

Isn't the code above going to change the state so that means its going to pause all videos in the rendered list itself? I mean the state is not going to apply directly only to 1 indexed item but all the videos that are rendered isnt that true?